# Python overview of different techniques used to apply a function to a list of elements

Tags: python-3.x, listiterator

I want to understand the following outcomes of the following techniques used in python3.X to perform certain things.  Consider the following code which using different techniques tries to achieve the same result.

```
def addSlash(fname):
    if isinstance(fname, str):
        if " " in fname:
            return fname.replace(" ", "\ ")


# example output
a = "ab c"
a = addSlash(a)
print(a)
print()


# list of interest
files = ["spaces file1", "spaces file2", "spaces file3"]

for f in files:
    f = addSlash(f)
    # this prints correct result but list elements are not permanently having the change.
    print(f)

print('\nThis did not change..')
print(files)


print('\nTrying the old way gives 2 slashes as well..')
files = ["spaces file1", "spaces file2", "spaces file3"]
for i in range(0, len(files)):
    files[i] = addSlash(files[i])
print(files)

print('\nTrying this way give as different results, putting 2 slashes instead of one for some reason')
files = ["spaces file1", "spaces file2", "spaces file3"]
files = [addSlash(f) for f in files]
print(files)

print('\nSame with this one, same results as above.')
files = ["spaces file1", "spaces file2", "spaces file3"]
f = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "\ "), files))
print(f)
```

The output of the above when running is the following:

```
ab\ c

spaces\ file1
spaces\ file2
spaces\ file3

This did not change..
['spaces file1', 'spaces file2', 'spaces file3']

Trying the old way gives 2 slashes instead of one!
['spaces\\ file1', 'spaces\\ file2', 'spaces\\ file3']

Trying this way give as different results, putting 2 slashes as well!
['spaces\\ file1', 'spaces\\ file2', 'spaces\\ file3']

Same with this one, same results as above.
['spaces\\ file1', 'spaces\\ file2', 'spaces\\ file3']
```

Can someone comment on each technique and explain why it does not work?

Comment: The doubled backslashes is just the difference between printing the string, and seeing the Python representation of the string. The latter will escape backslashes with another backslash. If you `[print(f) for f in files]`, the double backslashes will magically go away.

Comment: Also, `if "" in fname:` is meaningless... all strings contain the empty string. Did you mean `if " " in fname:`? (If that line got split weirdly, what I'm getting at is that I think you meant to put a space between the quotes.)

Comment: Yeah you are right about this, I meant that

Comment: Actually, that `if` statement isn't really needed at all. If the string contains no matches, `str.replace()` will simply do nothing.

Comment: By the way, I am not sure I completely understood if the double backslash is gonna be missing when I use it for my code or is going to be there

Comment: It's not actually there. Python just puts the extra backslash there when you look at the value of the object in the interpreter. When you're printing or passing the object around in a program, it will be correct. (Hint: what do you suppose `len('\\')` will return? Try it.)